# How do you tell Access Connections to automatically connect to LAN, and if none is present - connect to WiFi?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, thinkpad

How do you tell Access Connections to automatically connect to LAN, and if none is present - connect to WiFi?

I am running Windows 7.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about Microsoft Access?

Comment: No no no, I'm talking about the little Icon on the bottom right side of windows 7.. It's says it's called Access Connections when you hover/double click it.

Comment: I could be wrong, but that looks like a model specific software, i.e. dell wireless, hp wireless... could you post your PC's specs?

Comment: that screenshot is a Lenovo addition. It's not really part of windows 7.

Comment: @Joel.. Sorry, wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Access Connections, in the Advanced mode interface, go to Location Switching.

[image: Access Connections Advanced Options]

Then make sure the option to include ethernet connections is turned on.

From the Help manual:

> Optionally, if you want Access
>   Connections to check for available
>   wired networks (in addition to
>   wireless LAN networks) when switching
>   automatically, select Include Ethernet
>   connections in automatic switching and
>   prompt me to save Ethernet ports.
>
> If this option is enabled, Access
>   Connections will automatically obtain
>   identifying information (a MAC
>   address) for each new Ethernet port to
>   which you connect and then prompt you
>   to associate that port with the
>   location profile of your choice.  When
>   you subsequently connect to the same
>   Ethernet port, Access Connections will
>   apply the profile you selected.
>
> To view or delete the MAC addresses of
>   Ethernet ports which have been
>   associated with location profiles,
>   click Edit Saved Ports.

[image: Access Connection Location Switching]

Comment: Thanks so much for the elaborated user guide (-: Right now as can be seen at the screenshot I added, I can't Change my Ethernet priority (I guess it's because I'm not at work, so I'll be able to check it out only on Sunday). But thanks a lot for now!

Comment: @Oren A: I don't think you can change the priority of ethernet connections, as it is assumed that there can only be one of them connected at a time, and they override the WLAN connections.

Comment: Oh, and I think you have to go in to Edit Saved Ports, at the bottom, to give the 'Locations' for the ethernet connections.

Comment: but you wrote: "Put your ethernet connection at the top of the list.. " and now - "I don't think you can change the priority of ethernet connections.." What am I missing here?

Comment: @Oren A: It's been a couple of years since I have used this feature of Access Connections with ethernet ports, so I cannot remember clearly.  The screenshot you put up made me rethink that bit.  I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should already happen.  If you open up a command prompt and enter the `route print` command, you'll see your computers routing table.  One of the items in the table is a "metric".  In a nutshell, for a given destination it should the matching route with the lowest metric, and your LAN connection should generally have a lower metric than your wifi connection.

In this case, the Wireless connection must have somehow ended up with a lower metric.  You can use the `route` command to correct this, but it's not something I've had to mess with often enough to be able to walk you through it.

Comment: I really don't know what to say except that it doesn't.

Comment: @Oren - I updated my post to at least get you started on how to fix it.